# Using C3.js, when loading data via URL/JSON, is there a way to include groups in the data?

Tags: c3.js

If I'm creating a C3.js graph using:

`var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#my-chart-div',
    data: { 
      url: '/data/data.json', 
      mimeType: 'json',
      type: 'area',
      groups: [
        ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3']
      ]
    },
  });`

Is there a way for me to include the groupings (`thing1`, etc) in the URL-loaded JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to include groups in JSON data.

The best work-around I found to to this was using the [`onrendered` callback](http://c3js.org/reference.html#onrendered), and inside that callback, retrieve the data headers from the chart itself, then apply them in the grouping you want using [groups](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-groups):

```
onrendered: function () {
  if ( $('#chart-div').data('stacked') != true ) {
    chart.groups( [ chart.data().map(function(x){return x.id}) ]);
    $('#chart-div').data('stacked', true);
  }
}
```

Note the line that checks to see if the chart has already been stacked - applying a grouping to the chart re-renders it, which triggers this callback again (prevents an infinite loop).